# Does online compilers generate a.out/exe files on their servers?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

What kind of file is generated by online C/Cpp compiler like a.out (Linux) and .exe (in windows) but online compiler is browser based which can be used on both systems. So does it depend upon the server computer where the code gets compiled?

Comment: I'm concerned about the files generated which are completely OS and programming related. @machine_1

Answer (score 4):

If the server is running say *GNU/Linux* and they use the *gcc* compiler, they compile the program in the server and output a ELF executable, which is compatible with the *GNU/Linux* operating system, and there is no need for the web browser to know this.

When the program is executed, then the output is sent to the client (*the web broswer*) and you can interact with the program in a similar way by sending input from the browser and feeding it to the program through a pipe or some equivalent mechanism.

So what kind of executable is generated is irrelevant, and it depends on the compiler and operating system that the server is using.